# Open/Close workbook and Refresh Connection

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks on a shared network drive:

- Workbook A (Table)
- Workbook B (Pivot Table -Connected to source Workbook A)

I'm trying to, when Workbook B is opened, run macro and do this:

1. Unprotect a certain worksheet on Workbook B
2. If workbook A is Open, refresh data connections on workbook B
3. If workbook A is closed, open workbook A and refresh data connections on workbook B, then close workbook A.
4. Protect a certain worksheet on Workbook B

The code below works as intended in most scenarios when testing so far, but if someone else tries to open workbook B on their computer when someone else has Workbook A opened on another computer, it opens workbook A as a read-only file and keeps it open on their computer. I need it to close on their computer, and keep the initial one open that's on the other computer.

```
Public Sub RefreshPvt()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wkb As Workbook

If IsFileOpen("S:\\Testing\Job Closeout Status Test.xlsx") Then
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
Else
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(filename:="S:\\Testing\Job Closeout Status Test.xlsx")
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
wkb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End If

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Wait, why do you want to open workbook A in a new instance? There is absolutely no reason to do that, and it can cause some issues. So why do it?

Comment: I don't think you need to have the workbook A open. Still, opening it in **another Excel instance** is like opening it on another computer. Makes no sense and has no effect. If you want to open it, just open it in the same Excel instance where workbook B is.

Comment: Okay. I don't need it to open it in a new instance just have it opened when I refresh the connection.

Answer (score 0):

if you run ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll on workboook B in the immediate window does it work?

You could also make XLApp.Visible = true to see whether or not it's opening

I think you should be using something more like:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables

    pt.RefreshTable

Next pt
```

To do the whole workbook you could use:

```
Sub AllWorkbookPivots()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.RefreshTable
        Next pt
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I ran `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` on workbook B and it doesn't work. but when I hit the refresh button in the ribbon it works when I have workbook A open. The code does open workbook A when I changed `ExcelApp.Visible` from false to true and run the code manually. However the code doesn't run when I open Workbook B. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a point in opening the other workbook, but if you do, don't open it in another Excel instance. Separate Excel instances don't communicate.

Comment: Stupid mistake, I needed to unprotect the workbook before running `Thisworkbook.Refreshall`. It worked.

Comment: If I don't have workbook A open, it doesn't refresh the data. I get an error saying couldn't get data from Workbook A, have it open and try again.

Comment: Your solution to do the whole workbook got it to refresh the data. Thank you. The only piece I am missing is that I have to have Workbook A opened before that code runs. I tried to add my piece of code above to open workbook A. Workbook A opens, but I get a debug error saying couldn't get data from Workbook A to update pivot table, have it open and try again. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: When you press debug on the error what line of code is showing? Is it possible to message me the files. I can look in the morning

Comment: When I press debug It highlights `pt.RefreshTable`. I can send you the files no problem. Thank you.

Comment: I got it to work, but I have a slight issue. Perhaps you have an idea. I edited my post above to reflect the issue I am having. If you can take a look that would be appreciated.

Comment: are you saying that :

wkb.Close SaveChanges:=False

does not work if the file has been opened read-only? I would expect it to still work

Comment: It seems it doesn't want to close source workbook A if someone else tries to open workbook B on their computer when someone else has Workbook A opened on another computer, it opens workbook A as a read-only file and keeps it open on their computer. Everything works as intended when I test it out on one computer. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft Office tracks those locks using files that are created in the same directory as the original file. The document filename.xlsx gets a temporary lock file: ~$filename.xlsx. If the document is in use, other user/macro opens the document as read-only. It's by design.
>
> We might try to use Shared workbook feature of Excel, but there are some limitations.
>
> For more detail information, please refer to the following link:
>
> https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-79bd9dee-1aa3-49b5-bc27-a1ad28ffcbce

As mentioned here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c1b179e1-ec4a-4ab9-abf4-21dc8b0c9326/vba-excel-to-excel-data-connection-it-opens-the-source-file-at-refresh?forum=excel